# Создание архитектуры на основе реляционной DB MySql

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

И так, нужен совет в создании БД в которой будут хранится около 1.5 миллиона товаров, но вся сложность в том что у конкретного товара может быть к примеру 30 поставщиков, и для каждого поставщика надо хранить поля такие как: количество, цена, описание, и возможно еще какие то.
То есть к примеру если все это хранить в 1 таблице то было бы +30 каждого поля от поставщика(price_provider_1, price_provider_2...price_provider_30, description_1....description_30 и тд.)

На продажу выставится товар от одного поставщика который будет выбран по цене и количеству в наличии, но если у него не будет описания и картинки то это надо будет взять от другого поставщика.

Я пришел к такой реализации:

1. создаем таблицу `product`, в ней храним общие поля такие как `title, attr_id, category_id, manufacturer_id, provider_id, code, ...`
2. создаем таблицу `attributes` в ней храним поля поставщиков

Процесс импорта товаров(импорт включает в себя добавление новых или обновление количества/цены для существующих):

1. Если новый товар то записываем сначала данные в таблицу `attributes`, затем основные поля в `product` включая attr_id новой записи с таблицы `attributes`, проверка на существование товара идет по полям `provider_id` и `code`
   `provider_id - уникальный ID поставщика, тип int`
   `code - код изготовителя товара, этот код будет повторятся и у других поставщиков, тип varchar`
2. Если товар существует, то по `attr_id` обновляем таблицу `attributes`

Процесс выборки подходящего товара

Вариант 1:
Связываем эти 2 таблицы по полю code, так как он есть в обеих таблицах и тогда для одной записи в `products` получу все 30 вариантов от поставщиков и выберу все необходимое, но для этого надо будет сначала сгруппировать таблицу `products` по `code` что бы дубликатов не было

Вариант 2: без группировки, связать по полю `attr_id` и получить все вмести с дублями а потом отдельно отсеять ненужное.
При любом из подходов выборки подозреваю что нельзя будет работать напрямую с этими таблицами для отображения товаров, из за того что это будет возможно медленно, и придется делать еще одну таблицу что бы в неё импортировать уже отобранные товары с этих таблиц.
Выборка включает в себя пагинацию, поиск по товарам, фильтрацию по цене и количеству

Пару заметок:

1. Реализация будет на Laravel
2. Не допускается подключение других не реляционных БД, только MySQL

Меня не покидает чувство того что мой подход не правильный и принесет в будущем много головной боли, поэтому буду рад любому совету по том как это лучше реализовать, что бы работало максимально быстро силами MySQL + Laravel.

Comment: Полный анализ предметной области. Выделение сущностей и атрибутов, процессов и связей. Нормализация. Построенной по этим данным ER-диаграммы. Вот то, что Вы не сделали/пропустили. А структура БД - это всего лишь следствие пропущенных Вами шагов, а вовсе даже не самостоятельный продукт. Нет, в простейших случаях при наличии некоторого опыта может хватить и ощущений - но Ваш случай вряд ли простейший. Так что лучше сделайте по науке, чтобы не было потом мучительно больно. Опять же - поверьте - не Вы первый решаете именно такую задачу. Посмотрите на решения (и ошибки!) предшественников.

Comment: Похоже, что у вас классический случай отношения `многие-ко-многим`. Такое отношение строится из трех таблиц: `Продукты` `Поставщики` и связующая `ПродуктыПоставщики`.

Comment: @Bulson Если это не домашняя работа - то как минимум добавьте сюда историю изменения цены, категории цен, скидки и акции. И вот уже ни разу не простое M:N.

Comment: @Akina это верное замечание, но с чего-то надо начинать же.

Comment: Маленькое замечание. Если вы начинаете проектировать приложение со структуры БД, то вы очень быстро сядете в лужу. Начинать надо с построения бизнес моделей (классов) и их отношений друг с другом. Затем используете либо простые тестовые данные для моделей из текстовых файлов или записанных прямо в код и подгружаемых в память во время работы приложения, либо используете ORM и она сама вам построит нужную структуру БД. И быстро переключаетесь на разработку прототипного варианта UI и работы с моделями. Входе разработки вы столкнетесь с тем, что модели требуют доработки, а значит и изм. в БД.

Comment: Спасибо! учту. Это не совсем реальный проект, больше для обучение, но это не важно, интересно реализовать это так, как если бы это был реальный проект